# Limit of expression as x approaches 0

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I'm working with this limit, where I can't use any Maclaurin series, nor can I use L'Hopitals Rule. I'd be pleased if anyone could help me out with this one:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^{x^{2}}-\cos(x)}{\sin^2x}$$

I'm trying to convert the problem into a limit where I can work with the standard limits, such as $cos(x)/x$, but I'm not successful in doing so.

Thanks for any potential tips!

Comment: For what it's worth, whenever the use of L'Hopital's rule against specific functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ $~\left[ ~\text{i.e. consideration of} ~ \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} ~\right]~$ is prohibited, you can always fall back on a *proof from scratch* by poring over the proof of L'Hopital's rule, line by line.  Then, instead of invoking L'Hopital's rule, you implement the analysis within the proof, against the specific functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. ...see next comment

Comment: For example, googling on "L'Hopital's rule proof", one of the links was [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#Proof_of_L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule).  Therefore, you would choose one of the specific proofs in that link, and apply it to the specific values for $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ in the given problem.  As a shortcut, you can argue that the given $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ each have continuous derivatives everywhere.  This approach has the advantage of being industrial strength and requiring no knowledge of the limit of special fractions such as $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$.

Comment: Note further, that if (for example) $\frac{f(a)}{g(a)}$ and $\frac{f'(a)}{g'(a)}$ both evaluate to $\frac{0}{0}$, while $\frac{f''(a)}{g''(a)}$ does not, you can use the approach in the previous comment to show that [1] $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} = \frac{f''(a)}{g''(a)}$ and **then** show that [2] $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\frac{\mathrm e^{x^2}-\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)}=\frac{\mathrm e^{x^2}-1}{x^2}\cdot\frac{x^2}{\sin^2(x)}+\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2}\cdot\frac{x^2}{\sin^2(x)}
$$

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any tips on good resources where limits like these exists so I can do even more of them? I'm trying to look for limits like these online, however, I only seem to find limits from Calc 1, which isn't the level I want to work on atm. Do you know in what course this is taught?

Comment: Honestly I couldn't really tell